# How to make a form visible or invisible in C#

Tags: c#

So I have a Windows Form named Settings.CS

It has nothing.. the code is only this much

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace SteamBot
{
    public partial class Settings : Form
    {
        public Settings()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

Then I have another CLASS named Bot.CS. What I want to do is, after a specific function, I want the settings form to become visible. In VB it was just Settings.Visible = true

How do I do this in C#? Please help me.

Comment: Doubtful that this question actually has anything to do with making a form visible.  Surely the real problem is using a *type name* where an object reference is required.  Settings is a **type**, not an object reference.  You cannot use Settings.Visible = true in a C# program.  Unlearning the VB.NET syntax can be quite difficult.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution 1:** if you want to display the `Settings` Form first time, you need to create an instance variable of that `Form` and call `ShowDialog()` method to display it.

Try This:

```
void SpecificFunction()
{
    //--at the end of MyFunction call settings form

    Settings frmSettings=new Settings();
    frmSettings.ShowDialog();    
}
```

**Solution 2:** if you want to display the `Settings` Form which was hidden before , you need to to follow the below steps make it `Visible`.

**Step 1:** identify/obtain the `Settings` Form by using `Application.OpenForms[]` Collection.
**Step 2:** create a new instance variable of a `Form` by casting the obtained `Settings` Form in above step.
**Step 3:** Call the `Show()` Method on the created instance variable to `Show/Display` the `Settings` form.

Try This:

```
void SpecificFunction()
{
    //--at the end of MyFunction call settings form

    Form frmSettings = (Settings) Application.OpenForms["Settings"];
    frmSettings.Show();    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Lets assume that **Specific Function** is a **button click**

```
private void Button1_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e ) 
{
   Form1 myForm = new Form1();
   myForm.Show();
}
```

Replace Form1 with the form name of your settings form !

Answer (score 0):

I just created this new Form which is shown when the button is clicked:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Form f2 = new Form();
            f2.Visible = true;
            //f2.Show(); also works
        }
    }
}
```

You can also use 'this' if you want to manipulate the instance
give it a try